# Where can I find the URL for shortcut app icon bookmarks?

Tags: ios, safari, ipados, bookmarks, shortcuts-app

When you add a Shortcut as an app icon to your home menus it calls it a “book mark.” Is the URL visible somewhere? So I could save it as a Safari bookmark instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL is

```
shortcuts://run-shortcut?name=My%20Shortcut%20Name
```

where ‘My Shortcut Name’ is the name of the shortcut you want to run, and special characters are URL encoded (for example, spaces are converted to `%20`).

You can use this CyberChef recipe to get a URL encoded string for a given input: https://gchq.github.io/CyberChef/#recipe=URL_Encode(true)

For more information on the `shortcuts://run-shortcut` URL, see Apple's article:

- https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/shortcuts/apd624386f42/ios